# Terraform and RabbitMQ - Enable Plugins

Tags: rabbitmq, terraform

I am running a deployment using Terraform. This deployment requires a rabbitmq server with WebStomp enabled. I want WebStomp to be enabled automatically when terraform starts the rabbitmq server during apply. I have looked at the following:

1. Use a config file for RabbitMQ - don't see a way to link a config file with Terraform
2. Use a Provider - RabbitMQ providers listed on Terraform registry don't provide an option to enable this plugin
3. Can I use a provisioner? (see second "docker exec" in code block):

```
  # block until the service is running
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOT
            counter=0
            until [ "$(docker exec ${var.service_name} rabbitmq-diagnostics check_running)" ];
            do
              sleep 10
              counter=$((counter+1))
              if [ $counter -eq 90 ]; then
                echo "Unable to connect to service after 15 minutes. Exiting."
                exit 1
              fi
            done
            "$(docker exec ${var.service_name} rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_web_stomp)"
        EOT
  }
```

4. Otherwise WebStomp can be manually enabled, but the deployment needs to be automatic.

Comment: What's wrong with the code you provided? Any errors?

Comment: Is the platform's equivalent of `cloud-init` not an option here?